# Remove leading zeros from a negative value

Tags: php, trim

I'm using the `ltrim()` function to remove leading zero's from an already trimmed string, but unfortunately negative entries are also valid and thus my solution doesn't work for that.

For example -

```
$size1 = "0010xp";
$size2 = "-0010px";
var_dump(ltrim($size1, 0));
var_dump(ltrim($size2, 0));
```

Produces the output -

> string(4) "10px"     // Correct
>   string(7) "-0010px"  // Incorrect

How can I remove leading zero's from a negative value **while keeping the `-` symbol**?

Comment: You forgot to tag your question with the language you're using. Is that Java, C, Python...? It looks like PHP, but it could be anything

Comment: Good point, now sorted.

Comment: I think that, in this case, ordinary str_replace will do the job... $size2=str_replace('00','',$size2);  (works for positive number, too).

Comment: This would also remove zeroes after a non-zero number. In this very special case, it'll work, but not for long.

Comment: Yes, i know, if there are no multiple zeroes AFTER initial ones - it will work (that's why i didn't posted comment as answer):)

Comment: @nevermind - The vaule is taken from user input, so unfortunatly your solution wouldn't work in production, just in the case described in my question.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ltrim does take multiple characters:

```
$string = ltrim($string, '-0');
```

This will strip any zeroes and minus signs from the beginning of your string.

EDIT:
If you want to keep the minus sign, try something like this:

```
$string = ($string[0] == '-') ? '-'.ltrim(substr($string, 1), '0') : ltrim($string, '0');
```

preg_replace is also an option, but it is usually much slower than simple string operations.

Comment: @nevermind is correct, I would like to keep the `-` symbol. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My updated version keeps the - symbol. See the longer version above.

Comment: Ohh, I like - a cheeky one liner and no need for `preg_replace()`.  I think we have a winner :)

Comment: yeah, this is the one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just run ltrim twice?

```
$string = "-0010xp";
$string = ltrim($string, '-');
$string = ltrim($string, 0);
echo $string;
```

ltrim can take any character. See documentation. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

I you want to keep the "-" then see Steve B answer:

```
$string = "-00010px";
$string = preg_replace('/^(-)?(0+)/', '$1' , $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks, but a negative value is valid, so I don't want to lose the '-' symbol.

Comment: My bad. I have upated my answer. See Steve B answer

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function trimmer to check for the minus sign, remove it then add it back after removing the zeros.

You can then just call this with any string you want to strip the zeros from.

```
function trimmer($str) {
  $is_neg = false;
  if (substr($str, 0, 1) == '-') {
    $is_neg = true;
    $str = ltrim($str, '-');
  }
  $str = ltrim($str, 0);
  if ($is_neg) {
    $str = '-' . $str;
  }
  return $str;
}

echo trimmer("0010px");
echo trimmer("-0010px");
```

This will restore the '-' sign after trimming the zeros, which I don't think the other solutions do.

Comment: $string[0] is short for substr($string, 0, 1)

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thanks... is that compatible with older versions of PHP?

Comment: I was hoping that a one/two line solution existed, but this does the job so happy days.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: A shorter solution would probably be to use a regular expression - (see the preg_replace answers) but they can be a bit hard to follow if you're not used to writing them

Comment: @jx12345 I think it is a very basic functionality, so it should work down to at least PHP4. See https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (search for "String access and modification by character")

Comment: it stands to reason - just not seen it before in PHP, don't know why... cool. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution that comes to mind is to match on a regex and use preg_replace:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/^(-)?(0+)/', '$1' , "-00010px"));
var_dump(preg_replace('/^(-)?(0+)/', '$1' , "00010px"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but a negative value is valid, so I don't want to lose the '-' symbol.

Comment: This will keep a negative value. It swaps all leading zeros for either blank or for the minus symbol.

Comment: My bad, I did test but left another answer in above your code that stripped the `-`.  Confirmed that this does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$size1 = "0010xp";
$size2 = "-0010px";
var_dump(ltrim($size1, 0));
var_dump(ltrim(abs($size2), 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but a negative value is valid, so I don't want to lose the '-' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `floatval()`

```
$val1 = '0010px';
$val2 = '-0010px';

echo floatval($val1) . 'px';
echo '<br>';
echo floatval($val2) . 'px';
```

Output:

```
10px
-10px
```

@Psaniko answer might be more efficient though. And you need to add the 'px', which will be a problem if it is not only possible suffix.

Comment: Thanks, but as you summised, `px` is not the only suffix.